# Wrong monitor name, resolution, and refresh rate detected; possibly overriden EDID

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, resolution, refresh-rate, edid

- **Laptop**: Asus ROG GL552VW-CN108T
- **Monitor**: Iiyama G-MASTERG2530HSU-B1 (max 1920x1080 @75hz)
- **OS 1**: Windows 10 Edu (21H2)
- **OS 2**: Arch Linux (uninstalled in favor of fresh Windows install, but will set up later)

Monitor and Laptop are connected with HDMI.

### Problems

- Recommended resolution is 3840x2160 @30hz instead of 1920x1080 @75hz. This problem persists across all OSes.

  [image]
- Advanced Display Settings shows the **wrong** monitor name. When you Google this model you'll find another Iiyama monitor, which *does* support 3840x2160. I also have this monitor, but don't use it.

  [image]
- Can't pick 75 hz refresh rate, although the monitor supports this out of the box. Neither in 'List All Modes'; note that the title bar does show the correct monitor name, this is only because I installed the correct drivers on Iiyama's website. Prior to this the used drivers was "Generic PnP Monitor".

  [image]

  [image]
- Intel Graphics Command Center shows the exact same details: wrong monitor name, recommending 2160p instead of 1080p, no 75hz.
- After I had set the desktop resolution to 1080p manually, the active signal resolution (found in Advanced Display Settings) was at a higher setting.

### How and when this happened

These problems happened approx 6 months ago and I just lived with it by manually setting the resolution and refresh rate (still unable to pick 75hz). These problems started after I tried to setup a multi-monitor setup with my laptop, 1080p monitor, and 2160p monitor. In the end this wasn't feasible, so I unplugged all external monitors, plugged in the 1080p monitor, and faced these problems.

### What I have done/discovered

- Completely wiped the main drive, and freshly installed Windows 10.
- Reinstalled Intel HD Graphics 530 display adapter.
- Uninstalled all monitor drivers.
- Installed drivers for my monitor from Iiyama.
- Tried different HDMI cables.
- Reset both monitors to factory settings.
- Corrected the active signal resolution by picking the correct mode.
  [image]
- Pulled my hair out.
- Installed [Monitor Info View by NirSoft](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/monitor_info_view.html) and found some interesting results.
  [image]

### My conclusion

Judging from the last screenshot I think that my monitor's EDID somehow got overwritten. I'm not even sure if that's possible, I only just learned what EDID is an hour ago. You can see 2 monitor entries in the last screenshot called PLG2888UH where one is marked as active (it says 'yes' or 'no' directly next to the monitor name) and the other one as inactive.

The monitor marked as active has the wrong name, is not 27 but 24 inch, and should have a resolution of 1920x1080. The PLG2888UH marked as inactive is correct, as I also have this monitor, but don't use it.

It seems like at least the vertical frequency is correct, although 75 hz is only available at much lower resolutions.

---

I slowly lost my sanity over this problem for 6 months long. Tried to solve the problem multiple times, but eventually gave up. Until now I had no idea what was going on, now I feel like I have a sense for what's going on.

I am not shy of using a terminal if needed.

Comment: How is your monitor connected to the computer (HDMI, DP, etc.)?  Also--they do make "EDID Emulators" which sit between your monitor and the PC and return the emulator's EDID instead of the monitors (and you can program it).  But really weird for something to zap the EDID.  You may try uninstalling your monitor drivers and see if that fixes.

Comment: I haven't tested it, but perhaps you could set the refresh rate via https://www.monitortests.com/forum/Thread-Custom-Resolution-Utility-CRU

Comment: @LawrenceC The monitor is connected to my PC with HDMI. I have tried uninstalling whatever monitor drivers were available, after which tested, and installed the official drivers from Iiyama's website but to no avail. I have edited my post to reflect this info.